# Piping a passphrase to Veracrypt with popen() - is it secure?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, popen, veracrypt

I am trying to make mounting several Veracrypt volumes with the same password more convenient on the Linux commandline. Since Veracrypt does only support passphrase caching in GUI-mode, I wrote the following code to do the job for me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
if(argc > 1 && argc%2==1){
    srand(time(0));

    //prevent veracrypt from asking for user's passphrase
    system("sudo echo -n");

    char *buffer = getpass("Veracrypt Password:");

    for(int i = 1; i<argc; i+=2){
        char* cc;
        cc = (char *) malloc(57+strlen(argv[i])+1+strlen(argv[i+1]));
        strcpy(cc, "veracrypt -t --protect-hidden=no --keyfiles=\"\" --pim=123 ");
        strcat(cc, argv[i]);
        strcat(cc, " ");
        strcat(cc, argv[i+1]);

        FILE* fChild = popen(cc, "w");
        fprintf(fChild, "%s", buffer);
        pclose(fChild);

        free(cc);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(buffer); i++)
    buffer[i] = rand();
}
return 0;
}
```

The code works, but I wonder whether the passphrase is properly deleted from the memory after excecution. As shown in the code above, the passphrase is read into the char-array *buffer* in the beginning and replaced with random values in the end.

My two questions are:

- Is this approach a good idea at all? (securitywise)
- How is the value of *buffer* piped to veracrypt by popen()? / Is *buffer* read directly from its location or is it copied and can therefore remain somewhere in memory?

Comment: Seems fine to me. You are leaving no traces of the password in memory. As of popen() I am not sure if it is buffered or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach is ok and is as secure as is pipeing the password in the shell `<<<"myPassword" veracrypt`.

1. There is no password in the `ps` output.
2. The password is stored in temporary buffers only.
3. I think an attacker could still get the password using some side channel attacks, if it knows enough about your application/source code.

Your code is not secure at all.

1. You don't check the return value of malloc
2. You don't check the return value of popen
3. You don't check the return value of getpass
4. You overflow the allocated memory for `cc`. You didn't allocate place for the terminating null character. You could use `asnprintf` and let GNU library do the job for you.
5. Because you don't pass properly the `argv[i]` and `argv[i+1]` it's plain simple to attack any PC using your program, with just ex.:  `./your_program "; sudo rm -rf <some_file>" "; echo I can run any shell script here"`.

> Is this approach a good idea at all? (securitywise)

The approach is ok, how you approached it is not ok. Your program leaks memory and doesn't check any return values and has no control over the strings passed to `popen`, which is just unsecure. Using `system(sudo echo -n)` is also insecure. As for the approuch, would be best to bzero the buffer after it's last use `memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer) + 1)` (maybe multiple times, like 5), and then `free(buffer)`.

In the light of last attacks like Meltdown and Spectre and others, newer ssh versions encrypt the password with a long key (I think with RSA, not sure) right after receiving it from user and decrypt each time upon use. The key is long enough to make attacks using such methods not probable or too long. I don't think there is need for easy small application to implement such method. [source](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&m=156109087822676&w=2).

> How is the value of buffer piped to veracrypt by popen()?

Because you use `fprintf`, the buffer is copied into the internal `FILE*` buffer and then flushed on the newline. By default `FILE*` streams are buffered and flushed on newline. You can specify the behavior with `setvbuf`, however, I don't think it's safe at all, as the password will remain in the `FILE*` buffer for some time. Then the `fprintf` call writes the content of the internal `FILE*` buffer upon newline to the associated pipe file descriptor with the `FILE*` pointer. Then kernel passes the data from the pipe's input to the command's stdin. A little tiny bit safer way (as you don't need `printf` utility at all, you just `"%s"`...), is probably to use `setvbuf(fChild, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` and then to use `fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, fChild)`.

A proper approach would be to remove the `FILE*` and to use the proper `pipe()` + `fork()` + `exec()` and stream the password directly into the pipe with `write()` call, so you don't use `FILE*` internal buffering. `fork()` will also allow you to send signals and handle the return value of the child.

> Is buffer read directly from its location or is it copied and can therefore remain somewhere in memory?

Yes and yes and yes. It is read directly from it's location inside `fprintf` call. It is copied into internal `FILE*` buffer. It can therefore remain somewhere in memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer to my question.
I will improve my code according to your suggestions.
For clarification, I'd like to point out, that this code is not meant to be implemented anywhere outside my local
machine. For convenience I did not check any return values or the values of argv[], since I only call it manually.
In the final version I should definitely do so.

Comment: One thing is still not obvious to me: "Using system(sudo echo -n) is also insecure."
This line of code is just meant to ask the user for his passphrase in order to prevent veracrypt to ask for it. Veracrypt needs the permissions to mount the volume and could ask for the passphrase, when it is not cached yet. By this line I firstly don't have to condition on that case and secondly I don't have to worry about also passing the user's passphrase to veracrypt. I consider the caching done by sudo rather secure and don't see any problem with that.
Can you please elaborate on that.

Comment: And one more question: Regarding bzero-ing the buffer after its last use I am worried about providing information about the password length. Isn't writing random numbers to the location (maybe multiple times) the safer way to go?

Comment: Better would be add `veracrypt` to `sudoers` with `NOPASSWD:` then asking for sudo password each time. I think I meant it by that.